# Python : thread shuts down after receiving 0f byte over serial port

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, serial-port

I am making program for communication with cash register, and while i was testing printer on it (printing numbers from 0 to 100), I noticed that every time i get this byte (0f in hex) and my thread either blocks or shuts down. My project is made of 2 programs, one is for communication with cash register and tcp, and other is just sitting on tcp port (will add DB later)
So here is the 4 threaded program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import thread

import crcmod
import Queue
import serial
import socket
import time
#portovi
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT=5007

v =0
lockSerial = thread.allocate_lock()
lockTcp = thread.allocate_lock()
lockPrn = thread.allocate_lock()
serialBuff = []
tcpBuff = []
prnBuff = []
prnReady=1
stx = chr(0x02)
etx = chr(0x03)
ack = chr(0x06)
nack = chr(0x15)
prnCmd = ('PB','PD','PF','P'+chr(0xc2))
crc8 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x131, 0x00)

ser = serial.Serial( 0 , baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=2, timeout=None, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=None)
ser.open()
ser.sendBreak()
sl = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sl.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sl.listen(1)

connl, addr = sl.accept()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT+1))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
def toHex(s):
    lst = []
    for ch in s:
        hv = hex(ord(ch)).replace('0x', '')
        if len(hv) == 1:
            hv = '0'+hv
        lst.append(hv)

    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, lst)
#hex2bit
def hex2bit(string):    
    novi = bin(int(string, 16))[2:]
    if len(novi)<8:
        pom=8-len(novi)
        while pom!=0:
            novi = str(0)+novi
            pom=pom-1
    return novi
def serialRecv():
    messageSerRec = ''
    global prnReady
    while 1:

        byte = ser.read()#shuts down here
        if not toHex(byte)=='0f':#even if I change it it shuts down
            if byte == ack:
                print 'ACK'
            elif byte == nack:
                print 'NACK'
            else:
                if byte == stx:
                    messageSerRec = ''
                elif byte == etx:
                    messageSerRecFin = messageSerRec[:-2]
                    chSum = int ('0x%s'%messageSerRec[-2:],0)
                    if chSum == crc8(messageSerRecFin):
                        lockSerial.acquire()
                        serialBuff.append(messageSerRecFin)
                        print "Serial Recv: ", messageSerRecFin
                        lockSerial.release()
                        ser.write(ack)
                        prnReady = 1
                    else: ser.write(nack)
                else: messageSerRec = messageSerRec+byte
        time.sleep(0.01)

def tcpSend(): 
    while 1:
        if serialBuff:
            lockSerial.acquire()
            conn.send(serialBuff[0])
            print "Tcp Send: ", serialBuff[0]
            serialBuff.remove(serialBuff[0])
            lockSerial.release()
    time.sleep(0.01)

def tcpRecv():
    pom=""    
    while 1:
        messageTcpRec = connl.recv(25)
        i=0
        if len(messageTcpRec)>0:
            while i<len(messageTcpRec):
                if not messageTcpRec[i]==';':
                    pom=pom+messageTcpRec[i]
                else:
                    prnBuff.append(pom)
                    pom=""
                i=i+1
            print prnBuff
        #if not messageTcpRec=="":
        #    print "Tcp Recv: ", messageTcpRec
        #    if messageTcpRec[:2] in prnCmd:
        #        lockPrn.acquire()
        #        prnBuff.append(messageTcpRec)
        #        lockPrn.release()
        #    elif tcpBuff:
        #        lockTcp.acquire()
        #        tcpBuff.append(messageTcpRec)
        #        lockTcp.release()
    time.sleep(0.01)

def serialSend():
    global prnReady
    while 1:
        #print "prnRdy=", prnReady
        if tcpBuff:
            print "tcpBuff:", tcpBuff[0]
            lockTcp.acquire()
            ser.write(stx+tcpBuff[0]+hex(crc8(tcpBuff[0]))[-2:].upper()+etx)
            print "Serial Send: ", (tcpBuff[0])
            tcpBuff.remove(tcpBuff[0])
            lockTcp.release()
        if prnBuff:
            if prnReady == 1:
                lockPrn.acquire()
                ser.write(stx+prnBuff[0]+hex(crc8(prnBuff[0]))[-2:].upper()+etx)
                print "Serial Send(prn): ", (prnBuff[0])
                prnBuff.remove(prnBuff[0])
                lockPrn.release()
                prnReady = 0
        time.sleep(0.01)

thread.start_new_thread(serialRecv,())
thread.start_new_thread(tcpSend,())
thread.start_new_thread(tcpRecv,())
thread.start_new_thread(serialSend,())
while 1:pass
s.close()
```

So thread serialRecv shuts of when it receives that byte
I've been trying to work this out for last 2-3 days and can't find solution.

Comment: Pasting ~200 lines of code is not a great way to get help. Try to minimize it as mush as possible and still have it to showcase the problem you are seeing...

Comment: Removed second program (I don't think problem is there), but i cant minimize the first cause I'm not sure where is the problem.

Comment: It took too long for me to find the serialRecv method because of the poor formatting.  That, and the magic-number indexing is too much.  The whole lot seems to be controled by sleep() loops instead of signals. To do protocols, create a class for the protocol unit, push bytes in until it's full and valid, queue it off to whatever is going to use it and immediately create another one. Try very hard to not share the same structure directly between threads, if for no other reason than debugging becomes a nightmare, as you have found out.